# Swift: WKWebView warning and error messages (camera, inputs)

Tags: ios, swift, constraints, wkwebview, photo

I am seeing file upload warning and error messages using an HTML5 control in `WKWebView`, permission errors when taking a photo, and keyboard error (constraint) messages when accessing a webpage text input.

I would like to determine if I am missing permissions or configurations, or can safely ignore these messages. As far as I can tell I am not missing permissions.

In the case of the keyboard constraint error messages I believe these messages are internal to the swift api and not related to app code.

Below is abbreviated console output. Also, I created a test app which isolates these issues.

test app:  https://github.com/groundControlOne/DebugOne

full console output:  https://github.com/groundControlOne/DebugOne/blob/main/console_output.txt

Thanks

```
-- camera from html file upload control
2023-04-06 12:06:34.272287-0400 TestPhoneApp[15069:964420] [Camera] Attempted to change to mode Portrait with an unsupported device (BackWideDual). Auto device for both positions unsupported, returning Auto device for same position anyway (BackAuto).
2023-04-06 12:06:34.272356-0400 TestPhoneApp[15069:964420] [Camera] Attempted to change to mode Portrait with an unsupported device (BackWideDual). Auto device for both positions unsupported, returning Auto device for same position anyway (BackAuto).
2023-04-06 12:06:34.275919-0400 TestPhoneApp[15069:964420] [Camera] Attempted to change to mode Portrait with an unsupported device (BackAuto). Auto device for both positions unsupported, returning Auto device for same position anyway (BackAuto).
2023-04-06 12:06:34.275967-0400 TestPhoneApp[15069:964420] [Camera] Attempted to change to mode Portrait with an unsupported device (BackWideDual). Auto device for both positions unsupported, returning Auto device for same position anyway (BackAuto).

-- sandbox on select photo
2023-04-06 12:06:42.660708-0400 TestPhoneApp[15069:964420] [Sandbox] Could not enable Mach bootstrap, errno = 1.
2023-04-06 12:06:42.660792-0400 TestPhoneApp[15069:964420] [Sandbox] Could not enable Mach bootstrap, errno = 1.

-- save file
2023-04-06 12:06:45.756515-0400 TestPhoneApp[15069:964762] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
2023-04-06 12:06:45.756646-0400 TestPhoneApp[15069:964762] [ProcessSuspension] 0x111078270 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebKit uploads' for process with PID=15069, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
2023-04-06 12:06:45.757407-0400 TestPhoneApp[15069:964762] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
2023-04-06 12:06:45.757493-0400 TestPhoneApp[15069:964762] [ProcessSuspension] 0x111078310 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebKit uploads' for process with PID=15072, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
2023-04-06 12:06:45.757965-0400 TestPhoneApp[15069:964762] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>
2023-04-06 12:06:45.758028-0400 TestPhoneApp[15069:964762] [ProcessSuspension] 0x111078360 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebKit uploads' for process with PID=15070, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=originator doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}


-- keyboard display on text area
2023-04-06 12:06:50.728540-0400 TestPhoneApp[15069:964420] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x10394dcb0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x2820dbc40>> returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
2023-04-06 12:06:50.728659-0400 TestPhoneApp[15069:964420] API error: <_UIKBCompatInputView: 0x10394dcb0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); layer = <CALayer: 0x2820dbc40>> returned 0 width, assuming UIViewNoIntrinsicMetric
2023-04-06 12:06:50.765635-0400 TestPhoneApp[15069:964420] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x28031eda0 h=--& v=--& _UIToolbarContentView:0x103948ca0.width == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28037b7f0 H:|-(0)-[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x10394a400]   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x103948ca0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28037b840 H:[_UIButtonBarStackView:0x10394a400]-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIToolbarContentView:0x103948ca0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x2803192c0 'IB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(0)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x103859a90]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x103963250 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28031d540 'IB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(>=5)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x1039634d0]   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x103858250 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280319310 'IB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x103859a90]-(>=8)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x103963250 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28031dcc0 'IB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x1039634d0]-(>=5)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x103858250 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28031fc50 'TB_Leading_Leading' H:|-(8)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x1039652f0'Done']   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x103963d00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28031fd90 'TB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x1039652f0'Done']-(0)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x103963d00 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28031ed50 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x281942060'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading == _UIButtonBarButton:0x103963250.leading   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28031e210 'UISV-canvas-connection' UILayoutGuide:0x281942060'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.trailing == _UIButtonBarButton:0x103963d00.trailing   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28031e0d0 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x103963250]-(0)-[UIView:0x1038580a0]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28031ee90 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x1038580a0]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x103858250]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28031efd0 'UISV-spacing' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x103858250]-(0)-[UIView:0x103963b50]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28031e350 'UISV-spacing' H:[UIView:0x103963b50]-(0)-[_UIButtonBarButton:0x103963d00]   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28037b890 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x281942060'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x10394a400 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28037b930 'UIView-rightMargin-guide-constraint' H:[UILayoutGuide:0x281942060'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide']-(0)-|(LTR)   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarStackView:0x10394a400 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x280319310 'IB_Trailing_Trailing' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x103859a90]-(>=8)-|   (active, names: '|':_UIButtonBarButton:0x103963250 )>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2023-04-06 12:06:50.766851-0400 TestPhoneApp[15069:964420]
```

Comment: It would help if you removed the constraint related parts of the output and focus on just the messages you want help with.

Comment: This post implies that the  com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit is an Apple only entitlement.    https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/702207